# Are inheriting constructors noexcept(true) by default?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, noexcept, inheriting-constructors

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) I found that:

> Inheriting constructors [...] are all noexcept(true) by default, unless they are required to call a function that is noexcept(false), in which case these functions are noexcept(false).

Does it mean that in the following example the inherited constructor is `noexcept(true)`, even though it has been explicitly defined as `noexcept(false)` in the base class, or it is considered for itself as *a function that is noexcept(false)* to be called?

```
struct Base {
    Base() noexcept(false) { }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    using Base::Base;
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inherited constructor will also be `noexcept(false)` because as you quoted an inherited constructor will be `noexcept(true)` by default

> unless they are required to call a function that is noexcept(false)

When the `Derived` constructor runs it will also call the `Base` constructor which is `noexcept(false)`, therefore, the `Derived` constructor will also be `noexcept(false)`.

This is evidenced by the following.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
  Base() noexcept(false) { }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
  using Base::Base;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << noexcept(Derived());
}
```

Outputs 0.

Comment: I think that that part of the documentation on that site is pretty far from being clear... Anyway, it makes sense.